Make overlapping divs take z-index into consideration when using opacity
I can't for the life of me figure out why the higher z-index element is transparent where overlapped.  Any ideas what im doing wrong here?


.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.img1 {
  background: url('https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.img2 {
  background: url('https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 150px: left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="img1">
  </div>
  <div class="img2">

  </div>
</div>




Like, ellie down below, I don't understand the question. If you put two semi-transparent items on top of each other, of course, they will bleed into each other. Your overflow: hidden, on the parent element, does nothing because the parent element is much larger than the child image elements.

you also have a typo in the left value of img2

So what i would like to do is the overlapped portion,   I dont want it to bleed if there is a higher zindex on one of the elements. So both transparent but where overlapped only one element can be seen which has the higher zindex.

When working with opacity, the transparency remains even if you stack elements - that's the definition of transparency itself.
If what you're trying to do is to not have the top-left corner of the bottom image appear behind the top image, instead of using opacity we can use a filter (props to How do you simulate the opacity effect on an element without making it transparent?):
.img1 {
  background: url('https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  /*Remove opacity*/
  /*opacity: 0.3;*/
  --desired-opacity: 0.3
  --brightness: calc(2 - var(--desired-opacity));
  --contrast: calc(var(--desired-opacity) / (2 - var(--desired-opacity)));
  filter: contrast(var(--contrast)) brightness(var(--brightness));
}

This simulates the opacity property, based on a formula which can be found in the question I pointed to.
https://jsfiddle.net/4ftbukr8/5/

sorry - the overlapping position.  Updating the question.

I think I understand what you're trying to do. Updating the answer.

Updated my answer with a simpler solution. Hope this works for you.
